# Vue js input array for cloneable sections

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have input sections like so:

```
<div class="cloneable" data-id="0">                 
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Skills and Qualifications Titles</label>
            <input placeholder="ex : PHP, WordPress" name="skill.name" type="text" class="form-control" vmodel="skill.name">
            <span class="help-block text-danger" v-text="errors.get('skill.name')"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Skill Level %</label>
            <input placeholder="ex : 90" name="skill.percentage" type="text" class="form-control" v-model="skill.percentage">
            <span class="help-block text-danger" v-text="errors.get('skill.percentage')"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each section can be cloned to make a duplicate, so I am trying to array my data so I can access it backend like

```
skill[0]['name']
skill[1]['name']
skill[2]['name']
... etc
```

I am initiating the data like so:

```
skill: [
{
    'name': '',
    'percentage': ''
}
],
```

I have tried using the models like skill.index.name, but that doesn't work, how can I achieve what I am trying to do above?

Comment: Can you put together an example where it's not working? Fiddle, pen, whatever.

Comment: Do you clone by copying DOM elements, or by duplicating data items? Copying DOM elements will not work with Vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, you have an array of skills like:

```
skill: [
{'name': 'a_name', 'percentage': '20'}
{'name': 'b_name', 'percentage': '30'}
],
```

and you want to access a particular member of that array in your template. The normal way the arrays end up in templates is using a `v-for:` like:

```
<li v-for="a_skill in skill">
    {{ a_skill.name }}
</li>
```

…which would like all the skills in the array.

If you want to access a particular member of that array you will need to add the index like this:

```
<input v-model="skill[0].name"> // not skill.0.name
```

*(don't forget the hyphen in `v-model` it's missing in your example)*

You can even do that if you have some data you want to use as the index. For example:

```
  data () {
    return {
      skill: [
        {"name": "Foo"},
        {"name": "Bar"}
      ],
      i: 1
    }},
```

Then you could use this in your template:

```
<input v-model="skill[i].name">
```